# UISlider custom track image caps don't fill gradually

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a UISlider subclass where I set the minimum and maximum track image and thumb image:

```
setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(named: "TrackFilled")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5)), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(named: "Track")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5)), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "ThumbTest"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

and change the height:

```
override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var bounds = super.trackRectForBounds(bounds)
    bounds.size.height = 31
    return bounds
}
```

Which results into this, which is okay:

[image: UISlider center]

However, when the slider almost reaches the left or right ends, it 'snaps' to the end instead of gradually filling the caps (second image is the problem):

[image: UISlider before cap]

[image: UISlider bug?]

[image: UISlider end]

Any idea how this can be solved? Or is it an iOS bug and should I just create my own Slider? I've tried different height, changing the thumb, changing the thumb rect, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem... The left track image jumps to the end of the track when you move the thumb like at 80% of the track...

Comment: I found a solution, in my case the stretchable image margin was to big, I changed it for this: UIImage *sliderLeftTrackImage = [sliderLeftImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, screenScale*2.0, 0, screenScale*2.0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];